# Java netbeans form - taking value from combo box

Tags: java, string, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I want to take a value from a combo box and insert it in a method. My problem is the method needs to take variable of type Node.

> ShortestPath.computeRoutes(jComboBoxDepFrom.getSelectedItem().toString());

When I try the above code I get the following error:

> method computeRoutes in class busplanner.ShortestPath cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: busplanner.Node
>     found: java.lang.String
>     reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to busplanner.Node by method invocation conversion

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Isn't there a constructor or setter in the Node class that takes a String?

Answer (score 2):

You could place Nodes in the combobox, and use a renderer for the text per Node.

```
jComboBoxDepFrom.setRenderer(new BasicComboBoxRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                               Object value,
                                               int index,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Node node = (Node)value;
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, node.getText(),
                index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    };
});
```

If the Node.toString does not suffice.